# How code when when we type letter then should print word in another text field related to that

Tags: arrays, flutter

How code when when we type letter then  should print word in another text field related to that .[image]

like this image. In this image "i" == "india "So when type i then display india in another text feild.

```
This is my code
```

[image]

```
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'fruits',
          ),
          onChanged: (value) {
            fruits = letter;
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'fruits',
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              fruits = letter;

              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `==` in dart, doesn't map keys to values, it's the operator for checking equality, so if you print `letter` you'd see `[false, false, false]`.

You can do this with a `Map` that can be created with `{}`, check this out:

```
class APage extends StatefulWidget {
  const APage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<APage> createState() => _APageState();
}

class _APageState extends State<APage> {
  final map = {"a": "apple", "b": "Banana", "i": "india"};
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (v) {
                controller.text = map[v] ?? "";
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextField(
              controller: controller,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro , and also do you know how to make this, when we type ab in textified then display applebanana as a single word ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you like to have search filter.

```dart
class TAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  TAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TAnimation> createState() => _TAnimationState();
}

class _TAnimationState extends State<TAnimation> {
  List<String> data = ["in", "i", "India", "A"];

  List<String> filterItem = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              filterItem = data
                  .where((element) =>
                      element.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
                  .toList();

              setState(() {});
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: filterItem.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text("${filterItem[index]}"),
              );
            },
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```